# How can I match a row in the table to a passed in ID? Stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

For context:
I have a windows form with a datagrid populated with data from my SQL Server database. I have 'selected' a row that I want to edit. This 'edit' form has textboxes filled with the
selected rows data. I have then changed some of the data and want the changed data to be saved to the database.

This is a stored procedure I have written in SQL Server. I want the passed in ID (which is unchangeable to the user in the windows form) to match the ID in the table. This will allow the data to be changed from here. How can I match the ID fields?

```
alter procedure spData_Audit
    @ID int,
    @Name varchar(100),
    @Description varchar(3000), 
    @AdditionalInformation varchar(3000) = NULL
  
    as
    begin
    set nocount on;
            
        insert into dbo.Data (ID, Name, Description, AdditionalInformation)
        values(@ID, @Name, @Description, @AdditionalInformation)
        where @ID = ID
    end
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. Are you asking how to get the value of the ID from the selected row? Also, you said you want to change the data, that would indicate you want an update statement, not an insert statement.

Comment: I wasnt aware there was an update statement. I'm pretty new to SQL. I want to pass in the 'updated' data and update the correct row. Do I have to match the ID's to get the right row?

Comment: Yes. You would use a where clause in your update statement. You should check out the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 I would also look into getting some training before you go too far down the path here.

Comment: An `INSERT` *inserts* **new** data into a table. An `UPDATE` *updates* **existing** data in a table. A `DELETE` *deletes* **existing** data in a table. As you want to change the values, as mentioned, you need an `UPDATE`. A can't "insert" new values for an existing row, you need to update them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use an update for that. See example below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spData_Audit
    @ID INT,
    @Name VARCHAR(100),
    @Description VARCHAR(3000),
    @AdditionalInformation VARCHAR(3000) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE dbo.Data
    SET Name = @Name,
        Description = @Description,
        AdditionalInformation = @AdditionalInformation
    WHERE ID = @ID;
END;
```